# How to extend one tensor with another if they do not have the same size

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, tensor

```
a =  tensor([   [101,  103],
        [101,  1045]
    ])


b =  tensor([   [101,  777, 227],
        [101,  888, 228]
    ])
```

How to I get this tensor c from a and b:

```
c = a + b =  tensor([   [101,  103, 0],
        [101,  1045, 0],
        [101,  777, 227],
        [101,  888, 228]
        
    ])
```

I tried with c = torch.cat((a, b), dim=0) but does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you could try to pad the first tensor to the shape of the other. For this exact problem you could do that the following way:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

a = torch.tensor([
    [101,  103],
    [101,  1045]
])

b = torch.tensor([
    [101,  777, 227],
    [101,  888, 228]
])


a = F.pad(a, pad=(0, b.size()[1] - a.size()[1], 0, b.size()[0] - a.size()[0]), value=0)
print(a)
```

This extends the first and second dimension of the `a` tensor with zeros to match the `b` tensor.

You can then concat them:

```py
c = torch.cat((a, b), dim=0)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, it also works with: m =  torch.nn.ConstantPad1d((0,size_to_add), 0)
            masked_input = m(masked_input)